# What is the concept of only close window button in gnome shell

Tags: gnome

How to add minimize and maximize button in `gnome-shell` is a common question. My question is why gnome developer removed them? There should be a explanation. I am sure that they do it for more easy and sophisticated user experience, but how it improves the user experience?

Maximize functionality can be done using drag window to top panel or left/right. But what about minimize?

Another question is that why left launcher is hidden? I would have no idea about the opened application until i hit activities( spread view).

I know, i have asked it late. But i really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the reason but when I want to get rid of a window without closing it I put it in another workspace. I guess they wanted to leave more space for the windows by making the launcher disappear.